# How Firebase Works Internally on Flutter Dependencies

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies, firebase-analytics

Currently, I use Firebase in the Flutter project. Firebase Analytics library in detail.

However, I became curious when I used this library.

Firebase Analytics's services operate automatically **without any method calls from the entry point.**

All I have to do is add the dependencies of the project as follows:

```
dependencies:
  firebase_analytics: ^8.3.1
```

I don't know what procedures this is internally activated and moved by.

Can any experts explain how this is possible internally?

Answer (score 0):

> Firebase Analytics's services operate automatically without any method
> calls from the entry point.
>
> All I have to do is add the dependencies of the project:
>
> ```dart
>   dependencies:
>     firebase_analytics: ^8.3.1
> ```

That is not correct as there are a couple more processes to set it up.

Here is the step from the package's documentation:

- To use this plugin, add firebase_analytics as a dependency in your pubspec.yaml file.
- You must also configure firebase analytics for each platform project: Android and iOS.
  You need to add the `FirebaseAnalytics` object and the `FirebaseAnalyticsObserver` object to the `MaterialApp`:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();
  static FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer =
      FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Firebase Analytics Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[observer],
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: 'Firebase Analytics Demo',
        analytics: analytics,
        observer: observer,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The `FirebaseAnalyticsObserver` creates a NavigatorObserver that sends events to `FirebaseAnalytics`.

Comment: Except for conversion events, all events are logged by simply adding them to a dependency.